# Unable to add work item comment using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

[image]

I'm trying to add a comment to an azure devops work item, attached a screenshot with request API, request body and the response. This is what is available in the document as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples

Can anyone point me where I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `[ ]` from the json, is not valid:

```
{
   "text": "Moving to the right area path"
}
```